# Project training data onto PCA R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, pca, unsupervised-learning

I'm a total beginner in ML, R, you name it and I'm using **FactoMineR**'s **PCA** function on my training set to find the principal components of my data.

```
res_pca <- PCA(training, scale.unit=TRUE, graph=FALSE)
```

Now I have to project my training data onto the space spanned by the vectors found by PCA. How do I do that?

This is what I've tried:

```
# get_pca_var is from the factoextra package
var <- get_pca_var(res_pca)
# training_no_target is just the training dataset without the target variable, which is a factor 
train_pca <- as.matrix(training_no_target) %*% var$coord
train_pca <- data.frame(train_pca)
```

I think `train_pca` should now contain the final dataset onto which training my models... is this right?

Answer (score 1):

PCA is an unsupervised method that is used for *descriptive* modeling rather than *predictive* modeling. Therefore we don't usually think of projecting data with PCA as *training* per se. However it is possible to define a PCA space with one dataset and ask where new data falls into that same space. You were on the right track using the rotations (`p$var$coord`) to rotate the new data matrix with `%*%`.

Note you have to be careful to apply the same scaling and centering on your new data. This is also discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2592/how-to-project-a-new-vector-onto-pca-space).

Here's an example with the `iris` dataset where we define a PCA projection with half the data and then project the other half into that PCA space by `%*%`ing by the rotation.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(FactoMineR)

# split data
set.seed(1)
splits <- sample(nrow(iris), nrow(iris)/2)
train <- iris[splits,]
test <- iris[-splits,]

# build PCA rotation based on 'training' data
p <- train[,-5] %>% PCA(graph = F)

# projection of training data
p$ind$coord %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  bind_cols(., Species = train[,5]) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Dim.1, Dim.2)) +
  ggtitle("original points") +
  geom_point(aes(color = Species))
```

[image]

```r
# scale and project 'test' data into original PCA space
test[,-5] %>% 
  scale(center = p$call$centre, scale = p$call$scale.unit) %*% p$var$coord %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  bind_cols(., Species = test[,5]) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Dim.1, Dim.2)) +
  ggtitle("projection of new points into original space") +
  geom_point(aes(color = Species))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: So is ```p$ind$coord```, in your example, the dataset I should use to train my model? What's the difference between ```p$ind$coord``` and ```p$var$coord``` ?